# How can I get the text in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, data-mining

I want to get the text of an element in selenium. First I did this:

```
team1_names = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".home span"))
)

for kir in team1_names:
    print(kir.text)
```

It didn’t work out. So I tried this:

```
team1_name = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.home span')
print(team1_name.getText())
```

so `team1_name.text` doesn’t work either.
So what's wrong with it?

Comment: Hello there,  `.text`  is the correct way to get the text of an object however we need more context. When you say "it didn't wok out" and it "doesn't work", what happens? Is there an error?  - Also: What's the html source look like? Are you getting the right object (i.e. the object with the text)?  Can you share a link to the page so someone else can have a look directly and not guess at an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take care of a couple of things here:

- [presence_of_element_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262217/how-do-you-use-ec-presence-of-element-locatedby-id-mydynamicelement-excep/57313803#57313803) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.
- Additionally, [presence_of_element_located()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63197823/selenium-wait-for-all-class-elements/63197989#63197989) returns a [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139), not a list. Hence, iterating through `for` won't work.

---

### Solution

As a solution you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()`, and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".home span"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='home']//span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- The [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method *Gets the given attribute or property of the element*.
- The [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns *The text of the element*.
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)