# How to scrape all the Company Names within Stockrover website using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

If this code below scrapes the first company name, IBM from a table, how would I code it to scrape all the company names from the first column in the table?

Pertinent Code:

```
table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#gridview-1070-record-2989')))
```

For instance, the next one I need is #gridview-1070-record-2990 and so on.

Current Result:

```
IBM
```

Desired Results:

```
IBM
Microsoft Corporation
Apple Corporation
Google
Tesla
etc.
```

Full Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd

   
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
ser = Service("./chromedriver.exe")
browser = driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)

driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://stockrover.com")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/section[2]/div/ul/li[2]"))).click()
user = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
user.clear()
user.send_keys("vibajajo64")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("vincer64")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Sign In").click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)


table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#gridview-1070-record-2989')))
for tab in table:
  print(tab.text)
```

Comment: You seem to have posted your user name and access key in your code. I suggest you delete your post, change your keys, remove your keys from the code and post the question again.

Comment: Thanks, but it's just a dummy account with phony information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract and print the texts e.g. *IBM*, *Microsoft Corporation*, etc from all of the `<table>` elements within the website [stockrover](https://www.stockrover.com/), instead of [*presence_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63197989/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[id^='gridview-1070-record']")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[starts-with(@id, 'gridview-1070-record')]")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the pertinent code in a for loop and then format the string inputted to search according to an index like so

```
table = []
for i in range(2989,"""the number of the last record you need"""):
table.append(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#gridview-1070-record-{}'.format(i)))))
```

this will give you an array of the companies

Comment: Hi, I'm put your code in my initial post.  I getting some error when I print.  Tried a couple things but nothing has worked.  Any idea?         
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: did you try without the text attribute? just tab not tab.text

Comment: I just thought of it looks like you are still referencing the list try to make another for loop then try to get the text attribute. Make the foor loop nested