# Scraping Notion

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

After the bot clicks on the first book,it should wait until all quotes are visible; however, it doesn't. It only gets 4 quotes out of 25. It can get the 25 quotes if I `time.sleep(10)` but this is not efficient. How can I solve this?

```
class Scraping:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def openWebDriver(self):
        chromeOptions = Options()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chromeOptions) 

    
    def fetchNotion(self):
        self.driver.get('https://sumptuous-salesman-ca6.notion.site/bf68366a212e45e1ae9bee853867c225?v=85ee9cedeb5a44c994e49033053f593b')

    def getBooks(self):
        books = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="notion-selectable notion-page-block notion-collection-item"]')))
        books[0].click()
    def getQuotes(self):
        quotesElements = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@placeholder="Empty quote"]')))
        quotes = []
        for quoteElement in quotesElements:
            quotes.append(quoteElement.text)
        print(len(quotesElements))
        return quotes

scraping = Scraping()
scraping.openWebDriver()
scraping.fetchNotion()
scraping.getBooks()
scraping.getQuotes()
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close enough. Instead of [*presence_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63197989/7429447) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following *ocator strategies*:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  def getQuotes(self):
      print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[placeholder='Empty quote']")))])
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` in a single line:

  ```
  def getQuotes(self):
      print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerText") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@placeholder='Empty quote']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: What is the difference between presence and visibility of an element? I don't quite understand. Also, your code has the same problem: it doesn't detect all quotes because selenium doesn't wait until all of them load.

Comment: _What is the difference between presence and visibility of an element_: Did you get some time to check the embedded links?