# Getting text from a div + code object with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the text inside these div's but I'm not succeeding. They have a code between the class that doesn't change with each execution.

```
<div data-v-a5b90146="" class="html-content"> Text to be captured</div>
            

<div data-v-a5b90146="" class="html-content"><b> TEXT WANTED </b><div><br></div>
```

I've tried with XPATH, but I was not successful too.

```
content = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/b'))).text
```

Comment: What's the error? Also please add complete html  or the url so that the xpath can be verified

Comment: are you sure your xpath correct? also it is not recommended to use such full xpath selectors. Can you give more details of your HTML, pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change couple of things.

1. `presence_of_all_elements_located()` returns list of elements, so you can't use `.text` with a list. To get the text value of the element you need to iterate and then get the text.
2. `xpath` seems very fragile. you should use relative `xpath` since class name is unique you can use the classname.

your code should be like.

```
contents = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="html-content"][@data-v-a5b90146]')))
for content in contents:
   print(content.text)
```

---

You can use `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` as well

```
 contents = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="html-content"][@data-v-a5b90146]')))
 for content in contents:
     print(content.text)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. However, it does return a list of multiple strings. The text I want is on line 7, but when I write  list[6].text I get an error. How to access a specific list element?

Comment: Could you print your list how it’s look like. Without looking at the list I can’t say what’s the issue?

Comment: Through a for loop I was able to add the items to another normal list. The list that selenium returns is a specific type that does not respond to traditional python commands, as I could see.

Answer (score 1):

Both the `<div>` tags have the attribute *`class="html-content"`*

---

### Solution

To extract the texts from the `<div>` tags instead of [*presence_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63197989/7429447), you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and using [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72565083/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.html-content")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='html-content']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Try to get the element first then get the text from the element;

```
    element = WebDriverWait(
    driver,
    10
).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((
        By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/b'
    ))
)
content = element.text
```