# JavascriptException: Message: javascript error raised on driver.execute_script function

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting a JavascriptException trying to execute some JavaScript code on chrome driver, i am pretty confident the JS code is correct but I get:

```
 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: document.getElementByClassName is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.178)
```

My code:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementByClassName('hand card-stack fanned loose rotate-bottom ui-droppable').classList.add('selectedstack');")
elms = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, cards)))
for elm in elms:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','selectedcard')", elm)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elm)
```

Comment: `getElementByClassName` should be plural `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName - This is the function

Answer (score 1):

Use `getElementsByClassName`, There's no such method as `getElementByClassName`.

You code should be something like:

```js
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('hand card-stack fanned loose rotate-bottom ui-droppable')[0].classList.add('selectedstack');")
    elms = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, cards)))
    for elm in elms:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','selectedcard')", elm)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elm)
```

Answer (score 0):

### getElementsByClassName()

The [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method of [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s).

So instead of `getElementByClassName()` you should be using `getElementsByClassName()` and supply the index `[0]` as follows:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('hand card-stack fanned loose rotate-bottom ui-droppable')[0].classList.add('selectedstack');")
```

Additionally, as you are setting attribute values and invoking click on the elements within the *list* `elms`, instead of [*presence_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63197989/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) as follows:

```
elms = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, cards)))
```

So your effective code block will be:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('hand card-stack fanned loose rotate-bottom ui-droppable')[0].classList.add('selectedstack');")
elms = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, cards)))
for elm in elms:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','selectedcard')", elm)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elm)
```